# Unable to define a locator for checkbox in selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to define a locator for the below html code for a checkbox.[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrCgm.png)

I have tried through xpath, id, css but still the webdriver is unable to locate this checkbox.

Comment: can you add the HTML? and what you've tried..

Comment: is there an error?

Comment: Don't use pics! the HTML is better!!!

Comment: Use just `name` attribute of input for locating the checkbox element.

Comment: html code is in the hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

1.Find the top most Div in your case that will be checkbox

```
div[@class="checkbox"]
```

and then search for the label inside the Div.

So your full Xpath would be.

```
div[@class="checkbox"]/label
```

Try this and see if it works.

Comment: I am able to pick up the label, but it does not perform any action on checkbox. you can see the html code in the hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a check box is similar to clicking a button.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("idOfTheElement")).click();
```

will do.

However, you can also see whether the check box is already checked. The following snippet checks whether the check box is selected or not. If it is not selected, then it selects.

```
if ( !driver.findElement(By.id("idOfTheElement")).isSelected() )
{
     driver.findElement(By.id("idOfTheElement")).click();
}
```

Please share what you have tried, if this doesn't help.

Comment: I have tried this, by id it does not work. you can see the html code in the hyperlink